# Zero initialization of an array in c++ without an equal sign?

Tags: c++

I'm aware of `int a[10]={0}` and `int a[10]={}` but can you now also do `int a[10]{}` in c++ to initialize an automatic variable?

Comment: Is this a question or a statement of fact? There's a lot of ways to initialize things in C++ now, and not all use `=`.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: This was added in C++11. All objects can be initialized by curly braces without `=` sign

Comment: Yes, `int a[10]{};` is valid

Comment: Obligatory [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) by Nicolai Josuttis.  An hour long presentation on the initialization syntax pain point in C++.

Comment: also found this: Get to Know the New C++11 Initialization Forms at https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1852519

Comment: Good reading: [cppreference page on Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

Comment: @Eljay Ah, the short version!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All three are valid, but different initialization methods.

Since C++11 it goes something like this:

`={0}` is *copy-list-initialization* with a single element *braced-init-list*, which for a an array (because arrays are aggregate types) results in *aggregate initialization* from a single element, which in turn means that the first element of the array is initialized explicitly with `0` and the rest is implicitly *value-initialized*, meaning for `int`, they are *zero-initialized*, i.e. also initialized to `0`.

(There are a few exceptions where aggregate initialization is *not* performed for a single element braced-init-list even for an aggregate. Specifically if the single element is the same type or a type derived from the target type that is being initialized and if the single element is a string literal and the target a character array. In these situations the variable is initialized from the element of the braced-init-list instead.)

`={}` is *copy-list-initialization* with an empty *braced-init-list*, which does in the same way end up as _aggregate initialization, only that now no element of the array is explicitly initialized. Instead all of them are implicitly value-initialized and therefore zero-initialized.

`{}` is *direct-list-initialization* with an empty *braced-init-list*. For aggregate types there is no difference between *direct-list-initialization* and *copy-list-initialization*. They both end up as *aggregate initialization*. (In the first of the two exceptional cases I mentioned above there is a difference between the two, because the target would be *direct-initialized* or *copy-initialized* from the single element respectively.)

So in the end all three are valid and all of them initialize all of the `int` elements to `0`. More generally for arrays of scalar types all elements will be zero-initialized in all three variants.

However, for other types all three may have different behavior. Iterating all the relevant rules is unfortunately completely impossible in the scope of an answer here. In particular it is also possible to initialize non-aggregate types with list-initialization and it behaved differently from non-list-initialization in certain ways.

---

Before C++11 there was no general list-initialization, but only aggregate initialization, which was permitted only in the form using `=`.